# Find files filtered by multiple extensions

Tags: bash, find, filenames, file-extension

What is the correct syntax for:

```
find . -type f -name \*.\(shtml\|css\)
```

This works, but is inelegant:

```
find . -type f -name \*.shtml > f.txt && find . -type f -name \*.css >> f.txt
```

How to do the same, but in fewer keystrokes?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can combine different search expressions with the logical operators `-or` or `-and`, so your case can be written as

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.shtml" -or -name "*.css" \)
```

This also show that you do not need to escape special shell characters when you use quotes.

**Edit**

Since `-or` has lower precedence than the implied `-and` between `-type` and the first `-name` put name part into parentheses as suggested by Chris.

Comment: That will also print directories named "*.css".

Comment: Hmm, the parentheses in your updated version are a bit misplaced. The individual parentheses need to end up as separate parameters to *find*, so they need spaces around them (` "*.css"\) ` results in a single string value; it is the same as (e.g.) ` '*.css)' `). Second, the parentheses need to go around whole ‘primaries’ (the open parenthesis needs to be before `-name`, not between it and its ‘operand’).

Answer (score 19):

Here is one way to do your first version:

```
find -type f -regex ".*/.*\.\(shtml\|css\)"
```

Answer (score 15):

You need to parenthesize to only include files:

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.shtml" -o -name "*.css" \) -print
```

*Bonus*: this is POSIX-compliant syntax.

Answer (score 4):

I often find myself ending up using egrep, or longer pipes, or perl for even more complex filters:

```
find . -type f | egrep '\.(shtml|css)$'
find . -type f | perl -lne '/\.shtml|\.css|page\d+\.html$/ and print'
```

It may be somewhat less efficient but that isn't usually a concern, and for more complex stuff it's usually easier to construct and modify.

The standard caveat applies about not using this for files with weird filenames (e.g. containing newlines).

Comment: +1 for a clean and modular solution, the performance bottlenecks usually occur while processing the files resulted from the search results.